# Memoize elements of a list that have a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of checkboxes that I diplay. Whenever I press one, I add/remove it from a selection that I keep. For that, I use a callback function. However, once I reach a few hundred of boxes, it starts to become slow. I figured that I should memoize the ones that don't have to visually change. But, I cannot do that as long as they have to use the callback. If I don't update that, pressing a second button will unselect the first one, as the callback function has not updated. Is there a good workaround to this issue? Of course, I could store the state in the checkboxes, but then, whenever I want to perform an action on all selected boxes, I need to iterate over all boxes which exists, which I am not sure is efficient.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-margulis-3q84s?file=/src/App.js

Code example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
function Box(props) {
  return (
    <input
      readOnly={true}
      checked={props.selected}
      type="checkbox"
      onClick={props.click}
    />
  );
}
export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const click = (id) => () => {
    if (selected.includes(id))
      setSelected(selected.filter((name) => id !== name));
    else setSelected([...selected, id]);
  };
  const boxes = ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4"];
  const makeBox = (boxName) => (
    <Box selected={selected.includes(boxName)} click={click(boxName)} />
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Log boxes"
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(selected);
        }}
      ></input>
      {boxes.map(makeBox)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: following link might help you:https://kevinwkds.medium.com/react-memorized-hook-usecallback-usememo-react-memo-d11da7ebb9cc

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your question, I realized my comment was an answer. The answer is React will do that for you. You just need to give it the information it needs. The React error message is telling you that react can't figure out what it needs to redraw because you aren't giving the boxes a key prop. Changing makeBox to `(boxName, index) => { <Box key={index} ... />}` will let React know which boxes it needs to redraw.

This updated sandbox works efficiently with 1000 check boxes. https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-bird-56yfi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you add a log to the Box function, you will see that the function is getting called once for every box, even if you just select one :/